# Issue warning message to user upon clicking action button in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinybs

I am creating an application in Shiny in which a user can use slider inputs for two values. After that, the user can push an action button and see a scatterplot that only includes points that correspond to rows of a data frame that have values above the slider inputted values. That part of the application seems to be working.

However, the data frame can be very large if the user chooses smaller slider input values. As a result, if the user chooses slider input values that would cause more than 50 rows of the data frame to be plotted, then when the user clicks the action button, a warning message should appear (to indicate that the number of data frame rows might be large (greater than 50) and to suggest that the user choose smaller slider input values). If the user receives this message, but still clicks the action button a second time (without changing the slider inputs), then the >50 points are still plotted.

I have been doing some research on approaches, and am trying the shinyBS method popify(). However, my algorithm (lines 40-49 below) uses and if/else statement to decide if the warning message should be issued, and that part does not seem to be working. Moreover, I am unsure how to prevent the >50 points from being plotted unless the user ignores the warning message and clicks the action button a second time.

Any advice on how to accomplish this goal would be very much appreciated!

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(htmltools)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Click the button"),
  sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("slider"),
    sliderInput("val2", "Value 2:", min = 0, max = 1, value=0.5, step=0.1),
    uiOutput("uiExample")
    ),
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("plot1"),
    verbatimTextOutput("click")
  )
))

set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(Case = paste0("case",1:100), val1=runif(100,0,1), val2=runif(100,0,1))
dat$Case <- as.character(dat$Case)

xMax = max(dat$val1)
xMin = min(dat$val1)
yMax = max(dat$val2)
yMin = min(dat$val2)
maxTemp = max(abs(xMax), abs(xMin))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$slider <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("val1", "Value 1:", min=0, max=ceiling(maxTemp), value=0.5, step=0.1)
  })

  # datInput only validated once the go button is clicked
  datInput <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    subset(dat, val1 > input$val1 & val2 > input$val2)
  })

  output$uiExample <- renderUI({
    #if (nrow(datInput()>50)){
    #    tags$span(
   #       popify(actionButton("goButton", "Go!"), "Warning", "We recommend to choose val1 and val2 both to be greater than 0.5. If you wish to plot the selected values anyway, press Go again", trigger = "click")
  #      )
  #    }
  #else{
      actionButton("goButton", "Go!")
  #}
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    # will wait to render until datInput is validated
    plot_dat <- datInput()

    p <- qplot(plot_dat$val1, plot_dat$val2) + xlim(0, ceiling(maxTemp)) +ylim(0,1)
    ggplotly(p)
  })

  d <- reactive(event_data("plotly_selected"))
  output$click <- renderPrint({
    if (is.null(d())){
      "Click on a state to view event data"
    }
    else{
      #str(d()$pointNumber)
      datInput()[d()$pointNumber+1,] #Working now
    }
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Looking through your code I have to ask a few questions, why do you have `sliderInput("val2", "Value 2:", min = 0, max = 1, value=0.5, step=0.1),` in the UI and `sliderInput("val1", "Value 1:", min=0, max=ceiling(maxTemp), value=0.5, step=0.1)` in a `renderUI()`?

Comment: @Phi. Thank you, that is a good question. I have it that way because in my "real" app one of the slider inputs is dynamically generated based on the dat object (which the user will upload in the "real" app). I wanted to keep my example code above as similar to my "real" app in case the part I am stuck on would have a different solution depending on these other features.